Dynamically pick up topics to add to the KStream
I have a kafkastreams program that takes data on a topic pattern - "Test.*" and moves the message toa topic "Read".
Assume I can have 10s of Test.* topics like this - "Test.A", "Test.B", "Test.C" etc. Now, when the streams program starts, it can successfully read the data out of the topics that it finds at the startup and move it to final topic.
But, it does not pick up any new Topics that are added when the streams program is running. For Example, if I create a new topic "Test.XYZ" and publish data to this topic, this will not be processed and written to the "Read" topic.
How can I solve this problem?
Map<String, String> patterns = = new HashMap<>();
patterns.put("Test.*", "Read");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> pat: patterns.entrySet()) {
     Pattern topicPattern = Pattern.compile(pat.getKey());
     KStream<String, String> inputStream = builder.stream(topicPattern, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));            
     inputStream.to(pat.getValue(), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
}



The metadata refresh period for new topics defaults to 5 minutes 2) You're overriding inputStream in that loop, so it'll only process the last entry when you start that process (I assume you have more than one, otherwise, the loop isn't needed)

